# Add unique clickable links to each item in a dynamic list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a dynamically generated list, that when a user types in a keyword (such as "The"), a results set of all the books that include the word "The" in the title will appear. I want each of these results to have a link to a new scene in unity, and when the list item is clicked, it will open the scene in Unity that it links to. I've seen a lot of tutorials to do this with Buttons but not so much with text boxes?

I've tried with an IF statement on GetMouseButtonDown but I'm 99% sure thats not the correct way to go about it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Linq;


public class SearchBarMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string searchTerm;
    public GameObject inputField;
    public GameObject textDisplay;
    public string SceneName;

    public void Search() {

        searchTerm = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;

        List<string> Books= new List<string>() {
        "The Count of Monte Cristo",
        "Jayne Eire",
        "The Black Sheep",
        "In Search of Lost Time"
        };

        var result = Books.Where(str => str.IndexOf(searchTerm, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
        textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";

        if (result.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
                SceneName = item.ToString();
                textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text += SceneName + " \n";

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "None found, search again";
        }
    }
    void Start()
    { }

 }
```

Comment: you could probably use contains instead of index,im not sure your question is a question.. if you want to do a behaviour if something is true and something else is not.... there are limited options...

Comment: I'm mostly asking if I can have each string pulled out in the foreach loop can be a string but like, a clickable link at the same time. Sort of like google search results - type in the word "Eagle" and it brings up a list of results, and clicking one of them takes you to that specific page (aka open a scene that matches that name in unity)

Comment: well if you make them clickable, you can do whatever you need.. anything is clickable if you make it so :)

Comment: Well that's what I'm asking, I'm not sure how to do that. I'm new to unity and everything I search for just shows how to make buttons have onClick events, but since I'm generating the results list I need each individual result to have a unique link insrtead of making the whole results set one big link?

Comment: well you want the onlick so you can react and do something so that's a good place to start

Comment: [`button.onClick.AddListener`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)? Your current code only checks if the mouse is down *the same frame that a search is performed* and doesn't even check to make sure the mouse is over a specific item. Just "oh, the mouse is pressed, guess we get to go to this scene, and this one, and this one, and this one..."